# Spring form validation: unable to print errors in jsp

Tags: spring-mvc, jsp

I am working on spring mvc application, there I have a form where a user can change his password. I am validating this form by using default spring form validation (see validator code below).

JSP Page:

```html
    <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.strong textorg/tags/form" prefix="spring"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%>

    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title> Change password </title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <%@include file="index.jsp" %>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="container" style=" background-color: #F9FFED; ">
            <div>
                <h4><label>Change password:</label></h4> 
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-12" >
            <spring:form commandName="ChangePassword" action="ChangePassword.do" method="post">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="current_pwd"  >Current Password</label></td>
                    <td><spring:input path="current_pwd" type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Name"/></td>
                    <td><spring:errors path="current_pwd" type="text" cssStyle="color: red;"></spring:errors></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="newpassword"  >New Password</label></td>
                    <td><spring:input path="newpassword" type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Password"/></td>
                    <td><spring:errors path="newpassword" type="text" cssStyle="color: red;"></spring:errors></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="confirmPassword"  >Confirm Password</label></td>
                    <td><spring:input path="confirmPassword" type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Password"/></td>
                    <td><spring:errors path="confirmPassword" type="text" cssStyle="color: red;"></spring:errors></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"> SAVE </button> 
                        <a href="ListUsers.do" class="btn btn-success"> Cancel </a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>

            </table>

            </spring:form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

2. Controller get and post methods:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/ChangePassword",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String changePassword(ChangePassword chPaswd,BindingResult result,ModelMap model){
    chPaswd=new ChangePassword();
    model.addAttribute("ChangePassword",chPaswd);
    return "ChangePassword";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/ChangePassword",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String changePasswordPost(ChangePassword chpwd,BindingResult result,ModelMap model,HttpSession session){
    String message="";

    changepwdValidator.validate(chpwd, result);

    chpwd=new ChangePassword();

    if(result.hasFieldErrors()){
        System.out.println("Has errors");
        model.addAttribute("ChangePassword",chpwd);
        return "ChangePassword";
    }else{

        System.out.println("chnage pwd values :"+chpwd.getNewpassword()+","+"current pwd:"+chpwd.getCurrent_pwd());
        try{
           // some other operations

            model.addAttribute("ChangePassword",chpwd);
            }catch(Exception e){
                message="Failed to process the request, please re-verify the values!";
                model.addAttribute("message", message);   
            }
        return "ChangePassword";
    }
}
```

3. Validator class:

```
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.ValidationUtils;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

import com.knot.pirautomation.models.ChangePassword;

public class ChangePasswordValidator implements Validator{

    ChangePassword chngepwd;

    public boolean supports(Class clazz) {

        return ChangePassword.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        if(target instanceof ChangePassword){
            chngepwd=(ChangePassword) target;

            System.out.println("----------");
            System.out.println("Old pwd:"+chngepwd.getCurrent_pwd());
            System.out.println("new pwd:"+chngepwd.getNewpassword());
            System.out.println("confirm pwd:"+chngepwd.getConfirmPassword());
            System.out.println("----------");

            ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "newpassword", "NewPassword.required");
            ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "confirmPassword", "ConfirmPassword.required");
            ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "current_pwd", "Oldpassword.required");

            if( !(chngepwd.getNewpassword().equals(chngepwd.getConfirmPassword()))){
                errors.rejectValue("newpassword", "NewPassword.match");
            }
            if((chngepwd.getNewpassword().length()<8)){
                errors.rejectValue("newpassword", "NewPasswordlength.match" );
            }
            if((chngepwd.getConfirmPassword().length()<8)){
                errors.rejectValue("confirmPassword", "ConfirmPasswordlength.match" );
            }

            String blackListChars = "!'=();<> \"";
            char blackListArr[] = blackListChars.toCharArray();
            for(int i=0;i<blackListArr.length;i++) {
                if(chngepwd.getNewpassword().contains("" + blackListArr[i])) {
                    errors.rejectValue("newpassword","NewPassword.invalidChars"); 
                    break;
                }           
            }

            for(int i=0;i<blackListArr.length;i++) {
                if(chngepwd.getConfirmPassword().contains("" + blackListArr[i])) {
                    errors.rejectValue("confirmPassword","ConfirmPassword.invalidChars"); 
                    break;
                }           
            }
        }
    }
}
```

4. error.properties file:

```
Oldpassword.required= Old password is required
NewPassword.required= New password is required
ConfirmPassword.required= Confirm password should be required
NewPassword.match= Confirmation passwords should match
NewPasswordlength.match= New Password should be at least 8 characters
ConfirmPasswordlength.match= Confirm Password should be at least 8 characters
NewPassword.invalidChars=New Password has special characters which are not allowed
ConfirmPassword.invalidChars= Confirm Password has special characters which are not allowed
```

You can see that when the form has errors, I am returning control back to the same JSP.
My problem is that I am unable to trace the bug/error where my spring form validation is working fine, but when I am trying to display the errors which are defined in my properties file.

Answer (score 0):

You should not explicitly invoke validator. Use this validation method instead:

```java
@Valid @ModelAttribute("forName") FormName formName,
BindingResult bindingResult, Model model,
RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, HttpSession session
```

Comment: I amit, i used hibernate validator in the same way what you said.but it didn't worked fine.

Comment: The one i shared works fine for me and are spring validators not hibernate and there are few attributes like valid and then the order of formname and binding result is important. I would suggest to debug the code and see exactly what is happening.

Comment: Follow this example hope you might be able to fix the problem                 http://www.journaldev.com/2668/spring-mvc-form-validation-example-using-annotation-and-custom-validator-implementation